# Get sum of digits in string of key/value structure

Tags: sql, tableau-api, vertica

I have strings in vertica database like:

```
'a18: 2, b34: 5, n29: 10'
```

and i need to extracts digits from it and get sum. 
So the output should be:

```
17
```

(calculated 2+5+10)

I need it for working in Tableau.
How can i do it?

Comment: Do it in the application that is using the database instead of trying to do it in SQL. Or restructure your data so each value is in its own row in a table instead of having a bunch in a string.

Comment: What are your column names? Vertical databases can be normalised using the union operator.

Comment: @shawn i can't restructure data because i can just make selects to database. And also there can be different amount of 'keys' in this string: 
down vote
favorite
I have strings in vertica database like:

'a18: 2, b34: 5, n29: 10' or 
down vote
favorite
I have strings in vertica database like:

'a18: 2, b34: 5, n29: 10' or 'a18: 1, b34: 19'

Comment: @h33 this column name is 'category' but what does it change? this string is stored in one columns

Comment: @ChickChirik . . . You should fix your data model so you are not storing lists of things in a string column.  That is just poor database design.

Comment: @GordonLinoff but still maybe some regular expression would help me?

Comment: @ChickChirik . . . As far as I know, Vertica does not support arrays.  Nor does it have the ability to extract parts of a string into a separate table (i.e. table-valued functions).  You should fix the data model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While modifying the data model will make your life a lot easier, Your scenario can be handled using Tableau calculations alone.

1. Replace ':' by ','. This can be done using following calculation.

[image]

2. Get your total using following calculation. (This assumes maximum 5 key,value pairs. Adjust if required)

> ```
> ZN(INT((TRIM( SPLIT( [Formatted String], ",", 2 ) ))))+
> ZN(INT((TRIM( SPLIT( [Formatted String], ",", 4 ) ))))+
> ZN(INT((TRIM( SPLIT( [Formatted String], ",", 6 ) ))))+
> ZN(INT((TRIM( SPLIT( [Formatted String], ",", 8 ) ))))+
> ZN(INT((TRIM( SPLIT( [Formatted String], ",", 10 ) ))))
> ```

Here ZN replaces NULL with zero so that we dont have to worry about missing splits. We are simply taking alternate fields and converting them to integers.
[image]

Here is the final result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!! You saved me!

Answer (score 0):

Two steps, using the `SPLIT_PART` function, I think:

a) Verticalise your string into rows.

b) split your resulting strings by the colon, cast the token after the colon as an integer, and make a sum of those integers.

```
WITH  
-- this is your single-row input
-- if you have many rows, you will have to add any grouping column here                                                                                                                                                   
input(s) AS (
SELECT 'a18: 2, b34: 5, n29: 10'
)
,
-- start real WITH clause here ...
i(i) AS (
-- create 10 "index" integers out of nothing using TIMESERIES ...
 SELECT
   MICROSECOND(ts) AS i
 FROM (    SELECT TIMESTAMPADD(MICROSECOND,     1, '2000-01-01')
 UNION ALL SELECT TIMESTAMPADD(MICROSECOND,    10, '2000-01-01')
 ) limits(ts_lim)
 TIMESERIES ts AS '1 MICROSECOND' OVER (ORDER BY ts_lim)
)
,
-- verticalise your comma separated string
rows_obtained AS (
SELECT
  TRIM(SPLIT_PART(s,',',i)) AS row_obtained
FROM input CROSS JOIN i
WHERE SPLIT_PART(s,',',i) <> '' -- remove empty strings
--   you get:
--+   row_obtained
--+   a18: 2
--+   b34: 5
--+   n29: 10
)
-- get the sum of the second part of SPLIT_PART() by colon, cast to integer
SELECT
  SUM(SPLIT_PART(row_obtained,':',2)::INT) AS the_sum
FROM rows_obtained
;
```